# componentDidUpdate is not fired

Tags: reactjs, window-resize, react-lifecycle

In my source code, the height of the component `EditorBasic` that I measure by `.current.clientHeight` changes when resizing the window, which is not correct. To reproduce the bug, I wrote the following smaller code.

I used `aRef` to refer to `EditorBasic` and expected to get its height. I expect the following code to have the following behaviour:

1. When we click on "Click to toggle EditorBasic", by `updateTrigger`, `EditorBasic` will trigger `handleResize`.
2. `handleResize` calls `calculateNextHeight` which can print the height of the `EditorBasic` so that I could check.

But I cannot pass the 1st step; changing `updateTrigger` cannot trigger `handleResize`; the log `componentDidUpdate` is not printed.

Does anyone know why?

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-j4pm8x?file=App.tsx,EditorBasic.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import EditorBasic from './EditorBasic';

interface IAppProps {}

interface IAppState {
  showEditorBasic: boolean;
  updateTrigger: number;
}

export default class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
  aRef: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showEditorBasic: false,
      updateTrigger: 0,
    };
    this.aRef = React.createRef();
  }

  calculateNextHeight = () => {
    console.log(
      'this.aRef.current.clientHeight',
      this.aRef.current.clientHeight
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState({
              showEditorBasic: !this.state.showEditorBasic,
              updateTrigger: this.state.updateTrigger + 1,
            })
          }
        >
          Click to toggle EditorBasic
        </div>
        {this.state.showEditorBasic && (
          <div ref={this.aRef}>
            <EditorBasic
              calculateNextHeight={this.calculateNextHeight}
              updateTrigger={this.state.updateTrigger}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IEditorBasicProps {
  calculateNextHeight: any;
  updateTrigger;
}

interface IEditorBasicState {}

export default class EditorBasic extends React.Component<
  IEditorBasicProps,
  IEditorBasicState
> {
  handleResize() {
    // console.log('handleResize');
    this.props.calculateNextHeight();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // console.log('componentDidMount');
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    if (this.props['updateTrigger'] !== prevProps['updateTrigger']) {
      this.handleResize();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <br />
        EditorBasic {this.props.updateTrigger}
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `showEditorBasic` is completely recreateing the `BasicEditor`. In that case, the component will only trigger the `componentDidMount` function.

Try to call `handleResize` inside `componentDidMount` and render the `aRef` div outside your `if` statement.

App

```
import * as React from 'react';
import EditorBasic from './EditorBasic';

interface IAppProps {}

interface IAppState {
  showEditorBasic: boolean;
  updateTrigger: number;
}

export default class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
  aRef: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showEditorBasic: false,
      updateTrigger: 0,
    };
    this.aRef = React.createRef();
  }

  calculateNextHeight = () => {
    console.log(
      'this.aRef.current.clientHeight',
      this.aRef.current.clientHeight
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState({
              showEditorBasic: !this.state.showEditorBasic,
              updateTrigger: this.state.updateTrigger + 1,
            })
          }
        >
          Click to toggle EditorBasic
        </div>
          <div ref={this.aRef}>
            {this.state.showEditorBasic && (
              <EditorBasic
                calculateNextHeight={this.calculateNextHeight}
                updateTrigger={this.state.updateTrigger}
              />
            )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

EditorBasic

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IEditorBasicProps {
  calculateNextHeight: any;
  updateTrigger;
}

interface IEditorBasicState {}

export default class EditorBasic extends React.Component<
  IEditorBasicProps,
  IEditorBasicState
> {
  handleResize() {
    // console.log('handleResize');
    this.props.calculateNextHeight();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // console.log('componentDidMount');
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));
    this.handleResize();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    if (this.props['updateTrigger'] !== prevProps['updateTrigger']) {
      this.handleResize();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <br />
        EditorBasic {this.props.updateTrigger}
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is `updateTrigger` not considered as a property?

Comment: Yeah, I missunderstood your problem and made an update

Comment: Thank you. But I do need `showEditorBasic` as a part of my UI/UX. I tried to put `this.handleResize();` inside `componentDidMount()`, but it raised an error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'clientHeight')`. It seems that, at that moment, the aRef was not ready.

Comment: Because the `ref` is async. Can you put the div outside you `if` statement?

Answer (score 1):

React documents for componentDidUpdate:

> Called immediately after updating occurs. Not called for the initial render.

And you are rendering the EditorBasic when showEditorBasic is present and changing its props is simultaneous with the initial rendering.